# Three-digit score wraps in the related questions sidebar

Tags: bug, design

I'm pretty sure this question doesn't actually have 16/9 = 1.777... score.
[image: Example]

Comment: Or 11440, since that could also be a combination

Comment: (At least on this site; there is [one answer I know of](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/500202) that just topped that score...)

Comment: Perhaps Tom Bombadil is best viewed at 16:9 aspect ratio, even when the rest of the world is at 4:3.

Comment: Most of the world these days is actually 16:9, welcome to the 2010's!